# How to display an another html file when an option is selected in dropdown list?

Tags: function, drop-down-menu, innerhtml

How to display an another html file when an option is selected in dropdown list? I don't know what will I input next. I have html file for each option in the list. If I select an option in the list I want to display the html file in the `<div =id"cakes">`.  The html is located in the same folder as my index.

```js
function display() {
  var cake = document.getElementById("type").value;

  document.getElementById("cakes").innerHTML = link
}
```

```html
<select id="type" onchange="display()">
  <option value="special">Specialty Cakes</option>
  <option value="wedding">Wedding Cakes</option>
</select>

<div id="cakes">
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope It work with you.

```
function display() {
var cake = document.getElementById("type").value;
document.getElementById("cakes").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="'+cake+'.html" >   </object>';
}
```